# DialogFlow context is always empty in google assistant

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've made a simple chatbot on dialogflow by referencing the dialogflow documentation which is based on Dialogflow's fulfillment library. The bot works good on integration with Google Assistant.

However when I started using context (getting and setting context) in the node.js code, the bot doesn't work on google assistant. 
This line `agent.context.get('iotcontext');` is null in google assistant but works good in dialogflow test console.

Following is my code:

```
'use strict';
var https = require ('https');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    function welcome(agent) {
        agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
    }
    function fallback(agent) {
        agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
        agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
    }
    function myIntentHandler(agent) {
        console.log("Function myIntentHandler Run");
        const codeContext=agent.context.get("iotcontext");
        agent.add("Date spoken by user: "+codeContext.parameters["date.original"]);
    }
    // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
    // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
    intentMap.set('IoTIntent', myIntentHandler);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Context is fully supported for Google so there is an issue with the code. Of what type is your agent? Is it a dialogflow web client or an actionssdk object? I've had issues with Google Assistant when I used a dialogflow client in a project, though they aren't too different

Comment: Can you update your question to include as much code as possible? Contexts, both getting and setting, are definitely supported when using AoG, but its important to see how you're setting and getting them in your code.

Comment: updated my question with code